# Can't create spatial index on a SQL Azure table as PK isn't the clustered index

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, azure-sdk-.net

I need to create a spatial index for my geolocation column (`Geography` type), however the Azure SDK creates the table with the `CreatedAt` fields as the clustered index, instead of the Primary Key.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps has pretty specific requirements for supporting offline sync with large tables.  The semantics of the clustered index is one of those.  You can create a new EntityDomainManager copy that does the right thing.  However, it isn't available out of the box.

Just take the source for EntityDomainManager and EntityData - adjust it so that CreatedAt isn't a clustered index, and use your new classes as the domain manager.

Comment: Do I have any other option to have spatial search working? Even if offline sync won't be available (it's not a requirement of my project).

Comment: Azure Mobile Apps does not support spatial search (that is "give me records near a point or within a boundary"), so it's kind of moot - you need to use something else.  I'd probably implement a custom controller if offline is not a requirement.

Comment: I should have checked this support before. Thanks anyway, Adrian.